# Strange behaviour of fgets

Tags: c, block, fgets

Ive got a function here that blocks on fgets but when I print something before fgets it doesn't block.

```
int exec_command(char *command, char *output_buf, int buf_size)
{
    FILE* pipe = NULL;

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char tmp[SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned total_read = 0;

    pipe = popen( command, "r");
    if( !pipe )
    {
        //Error
        return -1;
    }

    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    while( !feof(pipe) ) 
    {
        //printf("reading"); //If I uncomment this fgets doesnt block
        if( fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), pipe) != NULL )
        {
            // check that it'll fit:
            size_t len = strlen(tmp);
            if (total_read + len >= sizeof(buffer))
                break;

            // and add it to the big buffer if it fits
            strcat(buffer, tmp);
            total_read += len;
        }
    }
    //Is there anything to copy
    if ( total_read )
    strncpy (output_buf, buffer, buf_size);

    return pclose(pipe);
}
```

Is there anything wrong on my function above?

Comment: Yes wrong, you don't close write end of process where you also reads.

Comment: [popen(3) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen") has useful info.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan - Can you please rephrase your message I cannot understand what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Its because whatever is writing your pipe isn't flushing its out buffer.  When you print, it ends up flushing that (not garenteed to happen though).  When you don't print, the pipe isn't actually getting written to because its because stored in a kernel buffer until it fills, and then the kernel will write the data. Call fsync or flush on the pipe fd in the process that is writing to the pipe to make sure that the kernel buffer is flushed.

Comment: The command I am calling is ifconfig. Wouldn't it automatically flush the pipe when the process is finished?

Comment: Ifconfig is obsolete. And no, it doesn't automatically flush the buffer on termination.

Comment: I just used select() to check if the stream is readable to fix this. Anyways thanks for reminding me that ifconfig is obsolete :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a new-line to the print-statement. It is (probably) line-buffered, and doesn't print until a new-line is encountered, you call [`fflush`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/).